# How do I count the frequencies of the letters in user input?

Tags: ruby, histogram

How do I count the frequency of letters that appear in the word "supercaliforniamightly" when the user enters a word like that in Ruby, and print out stars or asterisks to count the number of letters that appear?

Here's my code:

```
puts "Enter string: "
text= gets.chomp
text.downcase! 
words = text.split(//)

frequencies = Hash.new(0)

words.each{|item| frequencies[item] +=1}

frequencies = frequencies.sort_by{ |item, amount| amount}
frequencies.reverse! 

frequencies.each do |item, amount|
    puts item + " " + amount.to_s 
   end
```

The output I want is something like:

```
Enter a string: 
uuuuiiii
u , 4 ****
i , 4 ****
```

Comment: It took me awhile to understand your question. You start by saying, "How do you count the frequency of letters..." then proceed to present code that does that just fine. Presumably, your question concerns only the formatting of your output. In fact, the way you computed the frequencies is irrelevant. You might have just said that, for `"uuuuiii"`, you constructed a hash `h = { 'u'=>4, 'i=>3 }` and wanted to know how to produce the particular output format. In any event, in future please be clear about just what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the output a little bit (removed the space before the comma) so that I don't look like uneducated.

```
puts "Enter string: "
gets.chomp.downcase
.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)){|c, h| h[c] += 1}
.sort_by{|_, v| v}
.reverse
.each{|k, v| puts k + ", " + v.to_s + " " + "*" * v}
```

Output:

```
Enter string: 
uuuuiiii
i, 4 ****
u, 4 ****
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm curious if there is a more readable way of doing it?

Comment: Can you assign them to a variable to each of the statements?

Comment: Just put `x = ` before `gets ...` and `x = x` in front of the period in the relevant lines.

Comment: @user2353565, as you gain experience with Ruby you won't want to add local variables as you suggest, but doing that is a very good way to break down sequences of operations to help you figure out what each operation is doing. Here you might start with `a = "test string"; b = a.each_char; c = b.with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|c, h| h[c] += 1}` and so on. You will find `b` is an `Enumerator`. To see the elements they will enumerate, convert it to an array: `b.to_a`. (You could also break `c` down: `c = b.with_object(Hash.new(0)); d = c.each {|c, h| h[c] += 1}`).